# How to add remote repository URL in Bazzar?

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I am a git user but now I need to work on a project that is hosted on launchpad.

I noticed that git and bzr are similar but apparently have some confusing differences.

In git when you clone a remote repo the local copy is automatically hooked to the remote repo url. Apparently this is not the case in Bzr.

So how do I add the remote URL in bzr? In git I would do something like this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:bar/foo.git
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `bzr branch lp:project` that sets the *parent branch* for the local repo to the URL you specified. `bzr pull` will automatically use the parent branch, but `bzr push` requires that you specify the parent if you want to push to the parent, like so: `bzr push :parent`. You can add the `--remember` option to the push command to set the *push branch* so that you don't have to specify the `:parent` every time. You can see what the parent, push and pull branches are for your local repo using the `bzr info` command.

Comment: +1 for adding (a nice) answer even when an answer was already accepted.

Comment: Once you successfully push somewhere, Bazaar automatically remembers that location. The `--remember` flag is useful if you want to change the saved push location to a different one.

Answer (score 1):

In BAZAAR, this operation is called **bind**.
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/bind-help.html

```
bzr bind lp:~bzr/bzr-gtk/trunk
```

When I'm doing a checkout (branch) with TortoiseBzr, my working copy is automaticcaly bind to the branch origin.

Comment: Bear in mind that *bind* is not the same as adding a git remote. Binding to a remote repo means that every commit you make in your local repo will first be made in the remote repo. It's the equivalent of a SVN model.